# How can I set the type of azure service bus to notification hub programmatically

Tags: c#-4.0

Using methods below, I previously (until last week) could create a service bus with a "mixed" type and then could add a notification hub. However, it suddenly stopped working. It creates a service bus with "Messaging" type and when it tries to create the notification hub, I get the error below:

Enity xxxxxx, create notification hub failed with error forbidden

```
   public ServiceBusNamespaceResponse CreateServiceBus(SubscriptionCloudCredentials credentials, string regoin)
    { 
        var serviceBushubClient = CloudContext.Clients.CreateServiceBusManagementClient(credentials);
        var checkserviceBusResponse = serviceBushubClient.Namespaces.CheckAvailability(_deploymentName);

        if (checkserviceBusResponse.IsAvailable)
        {
            try
            {

                var serviceBusClientResponse = serviceBushubClient.Namespaces.Create(_deploymentName, regoin);
                _serviceBusEndpoint = serviceBusClientResponse.Namespace.ServiceBusEndpoint.ToString();  

                return serviceBusClientResponse;
            }

            catch (CloudException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ErrorMessage);
                return null;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

and

```
    public bool CreateNotificationHub(SubscriptionCloudCredentials credentials)
    {
        SBNotificationHubManager notificationHub;
        EntityDescription servesBus = new EntityDescription();
        servesBus.Name =_deploymentID;



        var des = new MyNotificationHubDescription("push-hub-" + TenantID, servesBus);
        notificationHub =
            ResourceFactory.Get( _subscriptionID,
                                new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(RowData._base64EncodedCert)),
                                SBRestResourceType.NHub, des) as SBNotificationHubManager;
        if (notificationHub != null)
        {
           // Console.WriteLine("Created Notification Hub: {0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, notificationHub.LookUp().ToString());

            if (notificationHub.Create())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Created Notification Hub: {0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, notificationHub.LookUp().ToString());
                notificationHub.WaitUntillActive();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I was wondering if something recently changed in azure? Can anyone please advise how to define the type of service bus (messaging/notification hub) when creating it in c#. The default with the above method is messaging. I need mixed, but notification hub type also works fine in my case.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Now you must explicitly select Messaging (for topics/queues/event hubs) or NotificationHub (for notification hubs). That is idea.

About implementation. Observing source codes I can see overload which accepts ServiceBusNamespaceCreateParameters argument:

```
Task<ServiceBusNamespaceResponse> CreateNamespaceAsync(string namespaceName, ServiceBusNamespaceCreateParameters namespaceEntity, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

That class has public property of NamespaceType

```
public NamespaceType NamespaceType{...
```

So you probably could set it to NamespaceType.NotificationHub and then go ahead to create namespace.

Comment: Thanks. Could you advise me what library and version you are using. Mine is v4.0.30319 and I can't see CreateNamespaceAsync and ServiceBusNamespaceCreateParameters.

Comment: I am just looking at the source code on the  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net